# How to trigger a dialogue box with a SwingWorker (External Class)

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I've been trying to familiarize myself with the use of SwingWorkers in Java. Is it possible to trigger a dialogue box to display from the GUI within a SwingWorker's process method?

Comment: @Titus, What have you done thus far? Also, there's an example in the [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) API that shows you how this would be done, even though it's quite silly.

Comment: @Titus: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215/can-a-progress-bar-be-used-in-a-class-outside-main/4637725#4637725) complements the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) example.

Answer (score 2):

> within a SwingWorker's process method

If you mean:

a) inside doInBackground(),

```
public Boolean doInBackground() {

  // caught exception half way e.g. login auth fail

  // 'push' into GUI layer (EDT)
  String text = "Your error here";
  publish(text);

  Boolean result = Boolean.TRUE;

  // continue with remaining process

  return result;
}

protected void process(List<Object> chunks) {
  String[] message = chunks.toArray(new String[chunks.size()]);

  // prompt user with dialog box
  JDialogBox.showMessageDialog(window, message);
}
```

---

b) inside done(),

```
protected void done() {
  // prompt user with dialog box
  String message;
  try {
    message = get();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  JDialogBox.showMessageDialog(window, message);
}
```

---

c) or outside get()?

```
SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {.....;
sw.execute();

// some time later

final String message;
try {
  message = sw.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

Runnable edt = new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    JDialogBox.showMessageDialog(window, message);
  }
}

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(edt);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes is that possible by implements [PropertyChangeListener()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html), there are two implementations (to avoids wrong implementations of methods)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProgressBar {

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestProgressBar");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestPBGui().getMainPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private TestProgressBar() {
    }
}

class TestPBGui {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    public TestPBGui() {
        JButton yourAttempt = new JButton("Your attempt to show Progress Bar");
        JButton myAttempt = new JButton("My attempt to show Progress Bar");
        yourAttempt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                yourAttemptActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        myAttempt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myAttemptActionPerformed();
            }
        });
        mainPanel.add(yourAttempt);
        mainPanel.add(myAttempt);
    }

    private void yourAttemptActionPerformed() {
        Window thisWin = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        JDialog progressDialog = new JDialog(thisWin, "Uploading...");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        contentPane.add(bar);
        progressDialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
        progressDialog.pack();
        progressDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Task task = new Task("Your attempt");
        task.execute();
        progressDialog.setVisible(true);
        while (!task.isDone()) {
        }
        progressDialog.dispose();
    }

    private void myAttemptActionPerformed() {
        Window thisWin = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
        final JDialog progressDialog = new JDialog(thisWin, "Uploading...");
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        contentPane.add(bar);
        progressDialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
        progressDialog.pack();
        progressDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final Task task = new Task("My attempt");
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("progress")) {
                    int progress = task.getProgress();
                    if (progress == 0) {
                        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    } else {
                        bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                        bar.setValue(progress);
                        progressDialog.dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        task.execute();
        progressDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
}

class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 4000;
    private String text;

    public Task(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        setProgress(0);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);// imitate a long-running task
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        setProgress(100);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        System.out.println(text + " is done");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```